# How can I get my build toolchain to resolve `src` references in an Angular2 inline template?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm writing a simple Angular2 component:

```
@Component({ ...,
  template: `
    <img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png">
  `, ...
})
```

I'm using a webpack config very similar to the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/webpack) so the `.component.ts` file is being passed through `awesome-typescript-loader`.  When I build the project, this component winds up with `<img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png">` in the page, i.e. the image URL isn't rewritten by Webpack.  I believe this is because inline templates aren't being parsed for `src` properties.

I have tried working around this by doing an explicit `require()`:

```
const SITE_LOGO = require("../img/logo.png");

@Component({ ...,
  template: `
    <img id="logo" [src]="logo">
  `, ...
})

export class AppComponent {
  logo = SITE_LOGO;
}
```

This seems like a lot of extra work, but it does get the job done -- the image winds up with `src="data:image/png;base64..."`.

It'd be nice to have sources fixed up automatically, but there's a bigger issue: when Webpack doesn't do the parsing, the assignment goes through Angular's DOM sanitizer and SVG images get prefixed with `unsafe:` which means they don't get rendered in the browser.  I see [a workaround that involves de-sanitizing the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080654/ionic-2-angular-2-images-prepended-with-unsafe-therefore-not-displaying-ev?rq=1) but it kind of seems like a hack.  I'd avoid all this if I could get Webpack to just rewrite my inline template for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) to teach webpack html-style "imports".

I have something like this in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/i,
    loader: 'html-loader?root=assets&attrs[]=img:src&attrs[]=image:src&attrs[]=image:xlink:href',
    exclude: ['./src/index.html']
}
```

P.S:
I don't remember if or why I had to specify this:

`?root=assets&attrs[]=img:src&attrs[]=image:src&attrs[]=image:xlink:href`

so maybe try seeing what's that first :)

Comment: This isn't going to help with inline templates, I don't think -- I do have some components that load the template from a URL source and I think those are working.

Comment: Hmm true, but I think avoiding inline templates is a good enough idea as it is :) especially if it solves your issue along with `html-loader`.

Comment: I had to add `html-loader` to my webpack config to get external templates working, but that broke the `<%= require(...) %>` that I had in my index.html.  `exclude` wasn't working for some reason so I changed the `test` to `/\.component\.html$/`.  I'd still like some kind of fix that allows me to use inline templates for very short components...

Comment: That's the limit of my experience with the issue then :)
Good luck!