# SVG image not coming properly on browser in angular 4

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, svg

I am working on angular 4 along with node and MySQL. I have saved my image .SVG in blob form but when i getting it back from API it is not able to get rendered on my browser. When i inspect it is showing me `<img src="unsafe : asd.......">` and when i remove unsafe then it is showing me the actual image. I am stuck on this problem. 
Help Needed.

```
<img src="data:{{asd.asd_logo_type}};base64,{{ico.ico_logo}}" alt="...">
```

unsafe keyword is automatically gets added image base64 string

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't save files into a database.. Saving files into a database makes it so much more complicated.. i advice you to store the path into the database instead.

Comment: @RaymondNijland We want to upload it on serve. That's the requirement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080654/ionic-2-angular-2-images-prepended-with-unsafe-therefore-not-displaying-ev/38083444#38083444

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel not working for me

Comment: You'll have to provide code if you want more assistance from the community

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel added

Comment: node.js servers supports file uploading with formidable in combination with fs packets.

Comment: Raj kumar @DanielWStrimpel means the complete code meaning the node.js code, angular code, MySQL tables with example data

Comment: @Rajkumar can you show how you tried to use that solution I linked to? Whenever you see that `unsafe` stuff it means you have to tell Angular that it really is safe

Comment: @Rajkumar  requirements are not commandments from deity, reamine your requirements,   I still don't see enough of a question to actually help you with.   Surprised not down voted yet